# Sql search in multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with multiple tables i.e table1, table2, table3 with same fields. Somehow I can't merge these tables into one.

Is there any way to query them one after another for same criteria such that if the record is found in the first table return the found record otherwise search in second table and so on. 
like:

```
Select * from table1 where cloumnX = 'xyz'
if found return the rocord
else
Select * from table2 where cloumnX = 'xyz'
...

Select * from lastTable where cloumnX = 'xyz'
```

Comment: If you have enumerated tables like that, you should consider fixing your schema design.

Comment: you can use `UNION`

Comment: Can you describe why you would want to do this? I have a feeling there is a better way than you are thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is your desired output but you can give a go to below:

```
if exists (Select 1 from table1 where cloumnX = 'xyz')
    Select * from table1 where cloumnX = 'xyz'
else if exists (Select 1 from table2 where cloumnX = 'xyz')
    Select * from table1 where cloumnX = 'xyz'
else if exists (Select 1 from table3 where cloumnX = 'xyz')
    Select * from table3 where cloumnX = 'xyz'
else
    print 'no records returned from tables'
```

or as mentioned in comments, use `UNION`, but then you need to remember about:

> "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must
>   have an equal number of expressions in their target lists"

```
Select * from table1 where cloumnX = 'xyz'
union
Select * from table2 where cloumnX = 'xyz'
union
Select * from table3 where cloumnX = 'xyz'
```

Comment: With regards to your second answer, the one utilizing the union:
While your query will join the tables, it fails to answer the second part of the question, and it may return the record from the second table first

Comment: @Eli, I am absolutely aware about that, however we are not really sure what OP wants, and seems like doesn't know that either as non of the answers have been accepted or even upvoted by him...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what you asked is actually what you need to do, this should do it:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT * 
INTO #table 
FROM table1 
WHERE cloumnX = 'xyz'

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #table 
    SELECT *
    FROM table2 
    WHERE cloumnX = 'xyz'

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #table 
        SELECT *
        FROM table3
        WHERE cloumnX = 'xyz'
    END
END

SELECT *
FROM #table
```

That said, You may be able to do this more optimally using other techniques. For example, the UNION mentioned above could work, but if different rows can be in more than one table for a given key value, you would need to include a field to ORDER BY, and use a TOP 1 in your SELECT statement to do what you asked.

Comment: Thanks dear, Looks like that is what i want. I have some tables with old records and some with new records, all with identical fields. The new table is not entirely new but updated. first i want to search a record in new table, if found, i will use it. otherwise i will search it in the old table. For some reason i don't want to combine tables and delete identical records that is why i need to query it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Muhammad,

I am going to agree with many of the others here, that this does look like there is room for improvement in the schema design; however, I do want to make a suggestion to the question asked, in a rather simple way. 
You can take the union all query here (union would eliminate nulls), and add a "rank" to it and select the top 1. See sample below.

```
select top 1 cloumnX from (
select 1 as ranked, * from table1  where cloumnX = 'xyz' union all                     
select 2 as ranked, * from table2  where cloumnX = 'xyz' union all                     
select 3 as ranked, * from table3  where cloumnX = 'xyz' 
)a
order by ranked
```

Again, while this may solve your issue in the short term, you need to rethink your schema if this is what you're experiencing.